# Class has no attribute X

Tags: python, oop

I've been working on making a combat test for a RPG game. For whatever reason I am getting a `class has no attribute` error.

Any ideas how to fix this?

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, name, H, STR):
        self.name = name
        self.H = H
        self.STR = STR

    def is_alive(self):
        return self.H > 0

    enemyturn = ["1", "2"]

class Goblin(Enemy):
    def __init__(self, name, H, STR):
        name = "Goblin"
        H = 50
        STR = 5
```

These classes are used in the code below:

```
if command == "1":
    Goblin.H -= Player.STR
    print("You strike the Goblin for {0} damage.".format(Player.STR))
    random.choice(enemyturn)
    if random.choice == "1":
        Player.H -= Goblin.STR
        print("The Goblin strikes you for {0} damage.".format(Player.STR))
        if random.choice == "2":
            pass
            Combat()
```

Comment: Which line returns this error?

Comment: @Marcin this one: `Goblin.H -= Player.STR`

Answer (score 3):

You are calling your attributes before the objects are instantiated.

You should declare them as class variables.

```
class Enemy:
    name = ""
    H = 0
    STR = 0

    def __init__(self, name, H, STR):
        self.name = name
        self.H = H
        self.STR = STR

    def is_alive(self):
        return self.H > 0


class Goblin(Enemy):
    def __init__(self, name, H, STR):
        self.name = "Goblin"
        self.H = 50
        self.STR = 5
```